# how use Varidic Template to inherit multiple interface

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Our project have to upgrade our serialization method from using XML to using JSON. For backward compatible reason, our class have to supply interfaces as :

```
class some_obj
{
public: 
    virtual bool Load(const CMarkup& xml); 
    virtual bool Load(const Json::Value& json);

    virtual bool Save(CMarup& xml);
    virtual bool Save(Json::Value& json);
}
```

I want to add a base class dealing with serialization issue, code as:

```
template<typename TImpl
        , typename Type = std::enable_if<details::SerializeTraits<TImpl>::result, details::SerializeTraits<TImpl>::ImplType>::type
    >
    class SerializableImpl
    {
    public:
        QappSerializable() = default;
        virtual ~QappSerializable() = default;

        virtual bool Load(const Type& value) = 0;
        virtual bool Save(Type& value) const = 0;
    };

    namespace details{
        template<typename Tag>
        struct SerializeTraits{
            enum{ result = false };
            //typedef typename T ImplType;
        };

        template<>
        struct SerializeTraits<CMarkup>
        {
            enum{result = true};
            typedef CMarkup ImplType;
        };

        template<>
        struct QappSerializeTraits<Json::Value>
        {
            enum{ result = true };
            typedef Json::Value ImplType;
        };
    }
```

After this, when a class have to be serialized, i can derive from base class , code like:

```
class some_xml_object: public SerializableImpl<CMarkup>
{
public:
    virtual bool Load(const CMarkup& xml){...; return true;}
    virtual bool Save(CMarkup& xml){...; return true;}
}

class some_json_object: public SerializableImpl<Json::value>
{
public:
    virtual bool Load(const Json::value& xml){...; return true;}
    virtual bool Save(Json::value& xml){...; return true;}
}
```

If i want to serialize as Json and XML, i have to derive from both `SerializableImpl<Json::value>` and `SerializableImpl<CMarkup>`. but i want a template more elegant using code like:
`class some_object : public serializable<CMarkup, Json::value>`

My question is:
How can i do this using Varidic template?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for this:

```
template <class... Type>
struct serializable : public SerializableImpl<Type>...
{};
```